# How Do I Use Safari's Input File Picker In My App?

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios

Whenever I use Safari to browse the web and come across a `<input type="file">` element, I can select it and Safari presents me with a popup menu (action sheet?) that looks like the following:

[image]

Is this type of control available to implement in my app? All I can find is [`UIImagePickerController`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimagepickercontroller) which seems to be just for picking images. I want the full range of options for choosing any file based on the different apps available on the user's device (Camera, Photo Library, iCloud, Dropbox, Google Drive, etc).

If not available in the traditional sense could I try to hack it in with a web view somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a [UIDocumentMenuViewController](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidocumentmenuviewcontroller).

See also [UIDocumentPickerViewController](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidocumentpickerviewcontroller).

Comment: Is it possible to have Camera and Photo Library access in a `UIDocumentMenuViewController`?

Comment: You can add whatever you like to the menu: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidocumentmenuviewcontroller/1614193-addoption